# creating a data framework using matrix tensor

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I want to create a data framework using matrix tensor. The framework should have the following features:

1. An `(n,n)` matrix, `m[t;i,j]`, indexed by `t=1,2,...,T`;
2. For each element `[t;i,j]` of `m`, create `k` more matrices, `m[t;i,j;k]`, each with the dimension `(n,n)`.
3. Notations: `t` denotes time; `[i,j]`,  matrix cell, and `k`, the number of sub-matrices coupled with `m[t;i,j]`.

I should be able to retrieve pairs of the coupled matrices across time t and for each element `[i,j]`. Suppose that I want to get the data for `t=3` and `t=7` for elements `[2,1]` and `[3,2]` and `k=3`, which is a total of `12` matrices. Each one of these 12 matrices is of `(n,n)` dimension.

This is quite complicated for me but creating a matrix tensor `m[t; i,j; k]` would make my life easier (with your help of course). Note that the tensor should accept the list of elements such as `{1,4,6,8..} for t, {(1,3), (2,1),...} for [i,j] and {1,2,...} for k`.

I hope someone can help me in building this data framework.

**EDIT 1**

Here is a visual matrix tensor for `t=1`, `n=2` and `k=2`. This matrix has been constructed using `Table` in a very primitive way, therefore I only give you the matrix I was imagining.

Original matrix `mat` and individual matrices for each element of `mat` are:

[image]

and  the final data framework is:

[image]

Blue sub-matrix (consisting of 2 matrices `k1` and `k2`) in the first column corresponds to cell `a[1,1]` of matrix  `mat`; green sub-matrix (consisting of `k1` and `k2`) in the first column corresponds to cell`a[2,1]` of `mat`; similarly, pink sub-matrix in the `2nd` column of `mat` is associated with `a[1,2]` of `'mat` and so on. This final big matrix is only for `t=1`.

Comment: can you post a concrete example of the desired result for  `t=1`, `n=2`, `k=2`, `ij =Tuples[Range[3], 2]`?

Comment: @kglr: I will post an example in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you can use `bigmat = KroneckerProduct[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], 
 Array[Subscript[a, #][##2] &, {k, n, n}]]`. How would `t` enter the picture; that is,  how would `bigmat` change when `t=5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[mat]
mat[n_, k_] := ArrayFlatten[Transpose /@ 
   Array[Array[Subscript[a, #][##2] &, {k, n, n}] &, {n, n}], 1]

MatrixForm[mat[2, 3]] // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_1(1,1) & a_1(1,2) \\
>  a_1(2,1) & a_1(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_1(1,1) & a_1(1,2) \\
>  a_1(2,1) & a_1(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_2(1,1) & a_2(1,2) \\
>  a_2(2,1) & a_2(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_2(1,1) & a_2(1,2) \\
>  a_2(2,1) & a_2(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_3(1,1) & a_3(1,2) \\
>  a_3(2,1) & a_3(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_3(1,1) & a_3(1,2) \\
>  a_3(2,1) & a_3(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_1(1,1) & a_1(1,2) \\
>  a_1(2,1) & a_1(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_1(1,1) & a_1(1,2) \\
>  a_1(2,1) & a_1(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_2(1,1) & a_2(1,2) \\
>  a_2(2,1) & a_2(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_2(1,1) & a_2(1,2) \\
>  a_2(2,1) & a_2(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_3(1,1) & a_3(1,2) \\
>  a_3(2,1) & a_3(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  a_3(1,1) & a_3(1,2) \\
>  a_3(2,1) & a_3(2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Yes, this is the main structure of the framework. This particular `mat` should have time index `t` because at each time `t` there is a new `mat` with the same dimension. How to retrieve the targeted data, for example, an element in `mat[t=3, n=2, k=4] is also critical.

Comment: @Tugrul, is the following  acceptable as the solution for the general case: `matrix[t_, n_, k_] :=  Array[a[#][#2, #3][#4][##5] &, {t, n, n, k, n, n}];` for `t = 3; n = 2; k = 3;` and  `matrix[3, 2, 3]` the whole structure and parts can be accessed using  using `Part`, .e.g., `matrix[3, 2, 3][[2, 1, 2, 3]]`.

Comment: Very neat work. I will work on it with an example to learn how to enter data in it. Can I use `Rule` to enter observations in the data framework? Any idea about the easiest way to enter data? Thanks very much for this marvelous code.